# Cycle through an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My array `var myImages = [];` that once i've `console.log()` the array (I push items in into it above) I get this back:

```
["01_img"]
["02_img"]
["03_img"]
["04_img"]
["05_img"]
```

Then `onClick` I change the background of a `div` to have a background image from the array.

```
$('.div_content').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + myImages + '.png)');
```

How do I change make it, so the background image I have changes `onClick`.

I tried as per example I found, but to no prevail:

```
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
      var myIndex = 1;
          myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(myImages.length);

          $('.div_content').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + myIndex + '.png)');)
    });
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Basically, each item in the array is an image name. So `onClick` I change the background image of a `div` with the item in the array. Issue i'm having is it always loads in the first array item. I need to `onClick` randomly choose an item from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem corectly you should only define your `myIndex` variable globally or in outer scope

```
var myIndex = 0;
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $('.div_content').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + myImages[myIndex] + '.png)');
    myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(myImages.length);
});
```

Comment: ...but not a *global*, just something that the click handler closes over. Global vars are to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited

Answer (score 2):

Each time you click the myIndex var is set to 1. Remove the line `var myIndex = 1;` and make `myIndex` as a global var.

Also you need to use `myImages[myIndex]` instead of `myIndex` which will fetch that value from `myIndex` as key from `myImages`

```
var myIndex = 0;

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
   myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(myImages.length);
   $('.div_content').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + myImages[myIndex] + '.png)');)
});
```

Comment: Also need to start a `0`, and increment *after* using the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myIndex = 0;
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
      // Short hand if: If the statement is true, use the first value, else (':') the second.
      myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(myImages.length);
      $('.div_content').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + myImages[myIndex] + '.png)');)
});
```

You should do this by declaring a global variable that stores you location in the array: `myIndex`, then incrementing that number and making sure it does not exceed the arrays length (minus 1, as array length starts at 0).

If you want a random pick from the array, try the following:

```
myIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length);
```

Then you can simple request the value at that location using `myImages[myIndex]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah yes I have never done it that way. Let me reinstate that.

Comment: It's really cool. :-) Say `length` is `5`. If you start with `i = 0`, then `i = (i + 1) % length`, `i` will go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Cool - if a bit hard to read (but that could be because I haven't a use for it yet.. Although this is probably good gallery material). Cheers